# Check all debian binaries against the checksum of the original

Tags: debian, packages, checksum, rootkit, md5

I would like to check all binaries on my server against

```
dpkg -e <path_to_deb_package> <destination>
```

(for example rkhunter could do this check against the originals when doing probupdate)

How could I check all packages with one script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the package [debsums](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/debsums).  Run `debsums -a` to check all packages.

Comment: cool, `debsums|grep -v OK` looks ok: http://pastebin.com/ff7hNZC0